# Missing required parameters for [Route: game] [URI: game/{type}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\game\resources\views\header.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I was learning Laravel for the first time so please help me, i'm using Laravel 6
Thank you so much <3
My bug

[image]

My html

[image]

My route

[image]

Please comment for more details.

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory if you ask me.

Comment: Put code instead of images.

Comment: Thats happen when you pass a null value as a required parameter. And please read the text on the following page about 'how to ask a question on SO' -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3):

edit your route

to

"Route::get('/game/{type?}', 'PagesController@getGame')->name('game');"

Answer (score 0):

Your route needs a parameter, which you defined by: {type}.
It seems in your header.blade.php you have called this route without passing a value with it, and for that reason you're getting this error.

Comment: @foreach($theloai as $tl)
            <div class="icon">
                <a href="{{route('game', ['type'=> $tl->idtheloai]) }}">
                <i class="{{$tl->anh}}"></i>
                <p>{{$tl->tentheloai}}</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            @endforeach         my html

Comment: Make sure that your variable is not null

Comment: And write your route like this: {{ route('game', $tl->idtheloai) }}

Comment: how to make variable not null, i'm not sure  :(

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check a variable not null,

First, check your variable is not null like:

```
@foreach($theloai as $tl)
    @if(isset($tl->idtheloai))
        <div class="icon">      
            <a href="{{route('game', ['type'=> $tl->idtheloai]) }}"> <i class="{{$tl->anh}}"></i> <p>{{$tl->tentheloai}}</p> </a>       
        </div>
    @endif 
@endforeach
```

OR

You can route with an optional parameter:

```
Route::get('/game/{type?}', 'PagesController@getGame')->name('game');
```

I don't know your controller logic. If your `type` is required in the controller then the first solution is good.

Comment: @Modric I have seen your controller code so `type` is required. use first solution.